# loading parameter files for data different sets

Tags: matlab

I need to analyse several sets of data which are associated with different parameter sets (one single set of parameters for each set of data). I'm currently struggling to find a good way to store these parameters such that they are readily available when analysing a specific dataset.

The first thing I tried was saving them in a script file `parameters.m` in the data directory and load them with `run([path_to_data,'/parameters.m'])`. I understand, however, that this is not good coding practice and it also gave me scoping problems (I think), as changes in `parameters.m` were not always reflected in my workspace variables. (Workspace variables were only changed after `Clear all` and rerunning the code.)

A clean solution would be to define a function `parameters()` in each data directory, but then again I would need to add the directory to the search path. Also I fear I might run into namespace collisions if I don't give the functions unique names. Using unique names is not very practical on the other hand...

Is there a better solution?

Comment: Is the relationship between parameter sets and data sets 1:1, 1:M, M:N, M:1 ?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark If I understand you correctly it's 1:1, i.e. for each set of data there is 1 fixed set of parameters. I analyse data from a physics experiment which is done in several runs, where the parameters change with each run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So define a `struct` or `cell array` called `parameters` and store it in the data directory it belongs in.  I don't know what your parameters look like, but ours might look like this:

```
parameters.relative_tolerance = 10e-6
parameters.absolute_tolerance = 10e-6
parameters.solver_type = 3
.
.
.
```

and I can write

```
save('parameter_file', 'parameters')
```

or even

```
save('parameter_file', '-struct', 'parameters', *fieldnames*)
```

The online help reveals how to use `-struct` to store fields from a structure as individual variables should that be useful to you.

Once you've got the parameters saved you can load them with the `load` command.

To sum up: create a variable (most likely a struct or cell array) called `parameters` and `save` it in the data directory for the experiment it refers to.  You then have all the usual Matlab tools for reading, writing and investigating the parameters as well as the data. I don't see a need for a solution more complicated than this (though your parameters may be complicated themselves).

Comment: It seems I didn't state the problem clear enough: I have several directories full of data (each for an experimental run). The data are mainly timetraces in binary format (10s to 100s MB). For each directory I need to store a different set of parameters. So in my code I would like to 1) select a directory, 2) read parameters, 3) read data, 4) use parameters to analyse data. The thing is, I would like to store the parameters in the data directories and read them from there.

Comment: I guess you're right and I was thinking too complicated. Thanks